# Get data of different table of same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in mysql

```
Users(id, username, email ,password(hashed))

Luckynumbers(id,luckynumber);
```

I want to do is ( i have session variable for username and id)
get the luckynumber corresponding to the id of user from Luckynumber table 
and store it as $_Session variable and echo it .

Please help

Comment: Well, sure I could write the code for you, but what have you tried?  I'd be happy to help you but which part are you stuck on?  schema planning?  database access?  sessions?

Comment: I just want the code to fetch the luckynumber in the luckynumber table of same user id i.e $_session['id'] as of users table and put it in a variable

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sarcastic.  SO isn't a free code writing service. You need to dig in, find some tutorials, and try something.  If something just doesn't click with you, feel free to ask a question about it.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select luckynumber
from users u join luckynumbers l
on (u.id = l.id and u.id = $_Session);
```

If the both table ID is same!!!